# A strange error occur about allocate array and rand()

Tags: arrays, exception, random

I want to fill big array with **rand()** function, when I define my array by **int h_in[N]**,the program crash in vs 2010,to my surprise, when I copy it to the online complier ideone [a link](http://ideone.com/)and everything is ok.Finally I define array by **h_in = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int))** in VS 2010,the program works.I can't figure out that and hope somebody point out my error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int N = 1024 * 1024;


int main()
{

    //int *h_in = (int *)malloc(N * sizeof(int));
    int h_in[N];
    float sum = 0.0f;
    srand(1);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        h_in[i] = (rand() & 0xFF);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int h_in[N];
```

is allocated on the stack.

```
int * h_in = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
```

is allocated on the heap. [BTW: don't cast the result of `malloc()`]

The default stack size is 1MB, so you should use a linker option to increase it:

[/F (Set Stack Size)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks(v=vs.100).aspx)